# Ruby - Merge two hashes with no like keys based on matching value

Tags: ruby

I would like to find an efficient way to merge two hashes together and the resulting hash must contain all original data **and a new key/value pair** based on criteria below.  There are no keys in common between the two hashes, however the key in one hash matches the value of a key in the adjacent hash.

Also note that the second hash is actually an array of hashes.

I am working with a relatively large data set, so looking for an efficient solution but hoping to keep the code readable at the same time since it will likely end up in production.

**Here is the structure of my data:**

```
# Hash
hsh1 = { "devicename1"=>"active", "devicename2"=>"passive", "devicename3"=>"passive" }

# Array of Hashes
hsh2 = [ { "host" => "devicename3", "secure" => true  },
         { "host" => "devicename2", "secure" => true  },
         { "host" => "devicename1", "secure" => false } ]
```

**Here is what I need to accomplish:**

I need to merge the data from `hsh1` into `hsh2` keeping all of the original key/value pairs in `hsh2` and adding a new key called `activation_status` using the the data in `hsh1`.

The resulting `hsh2` would be as follows:

```
hsh2 = [{ "host"=>"devicename3", "secure"=>true,  "activation_status"=>"passive" },
        { "host"=>"devicename2", "secure"=>true,  "activation_status"=>"passive" },
        { "host"=>"devicename1", "secure"=>false, "activation_status"=>"active"  }]
```

This may already be answered on StackOverflow but I looked for some time and couldn't find a match. My apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean by "large"? Just roughly. 1000? 1000000? 1000000000?

Comment: Good question, I thought about qualifying it.  In Ruby terms, I'll bet it's not that big.  Just shy of 10,000.

Comment: OK, then it should not be a problem to keep it all in the memory at once.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me editing your question. I simply reformatted to avoid the need for readers to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thanks Cary--not at all :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest something along the lines of:

```
hash3 = hash2.map do |nestling|
  host = nestling["host"]
  status = hash1[host]
  nestling["activation_status"] = status
  nestling
end
```

Which of course you can shrink down a bit. This version uses less variables and in-place edit of `hash2`:

```
hash2.each do |nestling|
  nestling["activation_status"] = hash1[nestling["host"]]
end
```

Comment: I will mark one of the answers correct tomorrow, I am fried and need to review this when I can think straight.  Both seem to work with the sample data, so I need to figure out how they differ and which is more the 'Ruby Way'.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
hsh2.map { |h| h.merge 'activation_status' => hsh1[h['host']] }
```

However, I think it will make a copy of the data instead of just walking the array of hashes and adding the appropriate key=>value pair. I don't think it would have a huge impact on performance unless your data set is large enough to consume a significant portion of the memory allocated to your app.

Comment: Fred, your solution will be marked correct one regardless of what sense other folks make--due to your awesome profile pic.  I'm a dad as of 11 months ago and that pic makes me happy :-)  Kidding of course, let's see what others come up with.  Thank you in advance--this is very concise.

Comment: congratulations - being a dad is the best!

Comment: I suggest you change the key from `:activation_status` to `"activation_status"` in order to match the expected result. I also suggest to either use `map` xor modify the existing array's elements (then use `each`).

Comment: good call on the index - the OP did specify a string key for the result hash

Comment: I will mark one of the answers correct tomorrow, I am fried and need to review this when I can think straight.  Both seem to work with the sample data, so I need to figure out how they differ and which is more the 'Ruby Way'.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not sure why at all, but when I use this code I get a `no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)` -- however, when I use Raffael's code, it works.  Can you explain how I could adapt this code (maybe to take into account `nil`'s or something?)

Comment: I can't see off hand where that error would come from. I didn't realize that operating on `nestling` inside of the `each` loop was actually operating on hsh2 in place. I think that makes @Raffael 's solution the superior one; that is, unless you wanted to keep `hsh2` the way it is and create a copy